# SPA RSA 2048 authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, rsa, single-page-application

I am developing SPA in angular and the specific requirement from customer to use RSA 2048 for authentication. I am a bit skeptical how the authentication token would get generated.  I believe the token would generate at the server side and it's server's responsibility to verify against the encrypted credentials.

Am I wrong in my thinking? Has anyone tried with 2048 RSA authentication earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how it will work,

1. Generated a public & private key using a `salt key` & `2048` bits.
2. Public key is kept within the source code to generate a `cipher text`.
3. Private key is kept on server to `decrypt` the cipher text.
4. Server will decrypt both the stored password ( already encrypted) with the login password ( encrypted).
5. If both decrypted cypher texts are equal , server will send the `auth-key` otherwise request is failed.